# Cards Inside ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-cardview, cardview

I have these cardView's inside ScrollView shown in the image-1( https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCnxz.jpg ) where the device is vertical and everything is as it's suppose to be but when the device is tilted Horizontally the 2nd row in the 4th row get's cutoff as shown here image-2(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P4hw.jpg). Please help on why this is happening and how can this be solved. (Note - in the 4th card there is a list view which is inflated by textview from colmn_row.xml)

activity_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
android:background="#ddd"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >




<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/num_stu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardview_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardview_list_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardview_image"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Students"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num_boys"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardview_list_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardview_image"
            android:textColor="#8b8b8b" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num_girls"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardview_list_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/num_boys"
            android:textColor="#8b8b8b" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_stu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/num_girls"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardview_image"
            android:textColor="#8b8b8b" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/num_teachers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/num_stu"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardview_image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardview_list_title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardview_image1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Staff"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numTeaching"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardview_list_title1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardview_image1"
            android:textColor="#8b8b8b" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/non_num_Teaching"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/numTeaching"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardview_image1"
            android:textColor="#8b8b8b" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/attendance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardview_image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardview_list_title2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardview_image2"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Attendance"
            android:textSize="24sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stuatten"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardview_list_title2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardview_image2"
            android:textColor="#8b8b8b"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/staffatten"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/stuatten"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardview_image2"
            android:textColor="#8b8b8b" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<!-- Fourth Card -->

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/notice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="ID"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
            android:text="Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:text="Date From"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Date To"/>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title" >
        </ListView>



</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

colmn_row.xml --

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="17sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gender"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="17sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="17sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="17sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you declared layout in layout-land folder?

Comment: @Vij i am not that familiar with front end development could you please explain what layout-land is and it's use . Thank you

Comment: copy that layout file in layout-land folder then you can see preview  for this you can refere this  https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: That didn't work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to the constant **layout_weight** value in **colmn_row.xml**,
**colmn_row.xml** will render according to device screen width. And All four item will share equal width.Make your column header also a device width specific.

Below is the code for 4th card layout,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/notice"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="ID"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Date From"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Date To"/>
   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dynamic_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Edit : It's a bad idea to put listview inside scrollview, try inflating layout inside LinearLayout as parent or use reyclerview inside NestedScrollView, I have updated lisview to linearlayout**

Below is the code to create viiew dynamically

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//....
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_layout);

    String[] demo = new String[]{"Hello","World","Java","Android"};
    linearLayout.removeAllViews();
    for(int i=0;i<demo.length;i++){
        addView(demo[i]);
    }
}

//Method to create view dynamically
private void addView(String data){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //You can use this view to findViewById, setOnClickListener, setText etc;
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.column_row,null,false);

    //FindView using inflated view
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    linearLayout.addView(view);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but didn't work out mush it also made the rows scrollable like this - https://imgur.com/a/vcwFa

Comment: @AsfanUlla sorry for that, its because list view was also there inside column header text's parent layout, Please see the updated answer. It will work now.

Comment: I am sorry if i am troubling you. your code really helped in aligning the textview contents but the 2nd row still does not appear when the phone is tilted to landscape. in this image i have scrolled way down but the second row does not seems to appear - https://imgur.com/vhJonvT  . i think it is something to do with the card itself i guess.

Comment: Try changing fill_parent to match_parent everywhere, fill_parent is depricated.

Comment: @AsfanUlla lemme try to reproduce this issue, and inform you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have a LinearLayout inside your ScrollView:

[image]

Try setting wrap_content to both layout_width and layout_height attributes.

Comment: Thank you for replying but when i remove that i am getting a new error - java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child